# Add conditions do activerecord includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, decorator

First I have this:

`has_one :guess
scope :with_guesses, ->{ includes(:guess) }`

Which loads all guesses (if they exists) for a 'X' model (run two queries). That's ok. works perfectly.

But I need to add one more condition to It.

If I do (my first thought):

`scope :with_guesses, ->(user) { includes(:guess).where("guesses.user_id = ?", user.id) }`

It will also run ok, BUT in one query (join) which will exclude results that doesn't have a 'guess'.

Any tips on how to use include with conditions but KEEPING the results that don't have a 'guess' ?

**UPDATE**

I ended up solving this by using a decorator, which I can pass the user as a context in the controller call, keeping the views clean.

I've used the Draper gem (https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to do this. You don't really need a gem to work with decorators in rails, but it can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but you can use something like

```
User.eager_load(:guesses).where("guesses.user_id = ?", user.id)
```

Comment: This code will work, but I still will have the same problem: In my case, only the 'matches' with guesses for the user passed in the scope will be loaded. What I want is to load all the matches even when they don't have a guess for the current user, and I think using a decorator (as mentioned in the update at the first post) is the best solution.

Comment: weird since `eager_load` performs an `outer join`. What does User.eager_load(:guesses) outputs ?

Answer (score 0):

when you using includes and where, the includes left join will be inner join.

so if you want to using a left join with where, you have to use string sql fragment:

```
scope :with_guesses, ->(user) { joins('left outer join guesses on guesses.user_id = ?', 

  user.id)}
```

I didn't test this code above, you have to test it yourself, this is just a way to think about

this problem.

here is reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: It will not work since you have to specify the matching columns for the joining tables, and not a external variable. What I really want is to specify another condition to the include in order to keep the queries running separeted and not excluding results without relations (see the console using join and includes to check what I am saying). Anyway, thank you for your effort in trying to help me.